# asp.net mvc OAuth external login failure on Azure (localhost ok)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth-2.0

I'm having difficulties with external login providers after deploying to Azure, I've been able to authenticate with the external providers (google and facebook) but recieve an error when the user clicks to register.

I was following this tutorial on using the 'membership API' and adding the 'canEdit' role.

Using the Membership API
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

It worked fine on localhost but when I deploy to Azure it successfully authenticates to Google or FB and gets to ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml and allows the user to press register, it then displays an error stating

'An error occurred while processing your request.'

I can connect to the Azure ASPNetUsers Table on the DB and I can that the user has been created, the user can actually click login and enter the site.  However the user hasn't been added to the 'canEdit' role, so it seems to partially complete or fail during the confirmation.  I don't understand why this works on localhost but not Azure, I've built a new deployment to Azure as well.  Could the error be in the Accountcontroller method for ExternalLoginConfirmation?  The error seems to happen when adding the user to the 'canEdit' role but not on localhost, only on Azure.

```
// POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = model.DisplayName,
                Email = model.Email,
                OAuthName = model.OAuthName,
                DisplayName = model.DisplayName,
                ForceID = model.ForceID,
                NeighID = model.NeighID,
                MyLatLng = model.MyLatLng
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "canEdit");
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Can anyone recommend basic debugging steps please?  Is there a way to see an error log?  (apologies as I'm new to this - guidance appreciated).

Comment: Couldn't understand. Is your problem with only Azure? Then you say "... (google and facebook) but recieve an error when the user clicks to register." . I suggest you to first identify your problem.

Comment: Hi Ozgur, yes the issue is only on Azure.  On localhost all works fine, user is authenticated by both OAuth providers and is successully entered to Aspnetusers table, user also has the new 'CanEdit' role assigned.  It is on Azure that I have the issue, the user is authenticated by FB & Google, gets to ExternalLoginConfirmation page, when pressing register the error appears.  The user can click login and is signed into the application, on inspection of the Azure DB, the user is in Aspnetuser table, but doesn't have the new 'canedit' role.  I've deployed twice to Azure, incl a new project.

Comment: I am Google & Facebook as OAuth2.0 providers to authenicate users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the Azure Database I found the new role wasn't present in the 'AspNetRoles' table, therefore it was adding the user to the 'AspNetUsers' table but giving the error when trying to allocate the role.

For anyone who may have a similar issue, the 3 tables to check are;

```
AspNetRoles - check all 'roles' are present 
AspNetUsers - check all 'users' are present
AspNetUserRoles - check user and associated roles
```

My error was in the way I was publishing the application, on the settings tab of the 'Publish Web Wizard' I wasn't selecting 'Execute Code First Migrations'.